# Spotify dislike commands with keyboard shurtcuts on Ubuntu 20

Tags: spotify

I am looking for a way to call the dislike action from the command line so to have it mapped to a custom keyboard shortcut.
I read a lot about dbus but using d-feet there is no commands associated to the dislike button.